# How I alter table nd modify a int type default null with some null entry to int type not null?

Tags: mysql

In my table contact, i is a integer column with default null value.and right now column do have some null entry.
Now I want to modify it in this way:

```
Alter table contact modify i int not null default 10;
```

But mysql giving error:invalid use of null value.
I m not getting why this so happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are defining a field as `NOT NULL` where some values are actually `NULL`

You can update the `NULL` entries before trying to alter the table :

```
UPDATE contact
SET i = 10
WHERE i IS NULL
```